# AttributeError: module transformers has no attribute TFGPTNeoForCausalLM

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, gpt-3

I cloned this repository/documentation https://huggingface.co/EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M

I get the below error whether I run it on google collab or locally. I also installed transformers using this

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

and made sure the configuration file is named as config.json

```
      5 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt-neo-125M/",from_tf=True)
----> 6 model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt-neo-125M",from_tf=True)
      7 
      8 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in __getattr__(self, name)

AttributeError: module transformers has no attribute TFGPTNeoForCausalLM
```

Full code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM 

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M",from_tf=True)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M",from_tf=True)
```

transformers-cli env results:

- `transformers` version: 4.10.0.dev0
- Platform: Linux-4.4.0-19041-Microsoft-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
- Python version: 3.8.5
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 1.9.0+cpu (False)
- Tensorflow version (GPU?): 2.5.0 (False)
- Flax version (CPU?/GPU?/TPU?): not installed (NA)
- Jax version: not installed
- JaxLib version: not installed
- Using GPU in script?:
- Using distributed or parallel set-up in script?:

Both collab and locally have TensorFlow 2.5.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to first edit the source code to remove the line that adds "TF" in front of the package as the correct transformers module is GPTNeoForCausalLM
, but somewhere in the source code it manually added a "TF" in front of it.

Secondly, before cloning the repository it is a must to run

```
 git lfs install.
```

This link helped me install git lfs properly https://askubuntu.com/questions/799341/how-to-install-git-lfs-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: TF in best guess refers to tensorflow. It gets enabled when you set `from_tf=True`.

Comment: makes sense, although I think it got triggered when I tried other flags as well, I don't remember now since it worked :p

Answer (score 2):

Try without using `from_tf=True` flag like below:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM 

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M")

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M")
```

`from_tf` expects the `pretrained_model_name_or_path` (i.e. the first parameter) to be a path to load saved Tensorflow checkpoints from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded the model by cloning this repository https://huggingface.co/EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M and I would like to load the model from that checkpoint hence I used the flag from_tf. A note, on google collab if I don’t use that flag it works fine but locally if I don’t use the flag it doesn’t work. On both collab and locally if I use the flag it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: Two possible causes of the error: (1) It might be the case `tensorflow` is not installed in your environment. (2) There is no tensorflow checkpoint in that repository huggingface.co/EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M/tree/main. Can you do `transformers-cli env` on your local machine?

Comment: I updated my question with the transformers-cli env results

Comment: I also tried using tensorflow-gpu instead of normal tensorflow on collab but I get the same error

Comment: I think the error was from a bug in the source codes. After making some changes I get this error, (opened github issue) https://github.com/EleutherAI/gpt-neo/issues/236